# Ubuntu 20.04 is not booting on My samsung Laptop "rcu_sched detected stalls on CPUs/tasks"

Tags: upgrade, 20.04, 19.10

Hi I updated my laptop(specs in the bottom) from ubuntu 19 to ubuntu 20.04 then I there were issues with the amd gpu which I fixed with replacing `quiet splash` with `radeon.modeset=0`
([My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it))

After getting through that; while its booting I see the ERROR message `rcu_sched detected stalls on CPUs/tasks`
and its stuck there for about 20 minutes and not going ahead

I see the same title for other questions in askubuntu but either they older versions of ubuntu or a different hardware/GPU or there are no suggested solutions

[Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejHVL.jpg)

*I see the same issue when I try to boot up ubuntu 20.04 from my thumb-drive as well*

[My laptop Link to the product](https://www.bestbuy.com/site/samsung-notebook-9-pro-15-touch-screen-laptop-intel-core-i7-16gb-memory-amd-radeon-540-256gb-solid-state-drive-titan-silver/6111205.p?skuId=6111205)

My hardware specs

```
Graphics -- AMD Radeon Video MemoryInfo 2000 megabytes
Processor-- Processor Brand Intel Processor Speed (Base)Info
1.8 gigahertz
Processor ModelInfo
Intel 8th Generation Core i7
Processor Model Number
i7-8550U
```

MotherBoard Info

```
$$>wmic baseboard get product,Manufacturer,version,serialnumber
Manufacturer                   Product         SerialNumber    Version
SAMSUNG ELECTRONICS CO., LTD.  NP940X5N-X01US  123490EN400015  SGL9887A03-C01-G001-S0002+10.0.17763

wmic bios get smbiosbiosversion
SMBIOSBIOSVersion
P05AGQ.033.181123.PS

Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.0.0 present.

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 15 bytes
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: SAMSUNG ELECTRONICS CO., LTD.
    Product Name: NP940X5N-X01US
    Version: SGL9887A03-C01-G001-S0002+10.0.17763
    Serial Number: 123490EN400015
    Asset Tag: No Asset Tag
    Features:
        Board is a hosting board
        Board is replaceable
    Location In Chassis: Middle
    Chassis Handle: 0x0003
    Type: Motherboard
    Contained Object Handles: 0

Handle 0x0008, DMI type 10, 10 bytes
On Board Device 1 Information
    Type: Video
    Status: Enabled
    Description: Onboard GFx
On Board Device 2 Information
    Type: Ethernet
    Status: Enabled
    Description: Onboard WLAN
On Board Device 3 Information
    Type: Other
    Status: Enabled
    Description: Onboard SATA

Handle 0x0012, DMI type 41, 11 bytes
Onboard Device
    Reference Designation:  Onboard IGD
    Type: Video
    Status: Enabled
    Type Instance: 1
    Bus Address: 0000:00:02.0
```

Comment: radeon.modeset=0 disables the AMD drivers. Not the right fix. Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `ps auxc | grep -i therm`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema with the installed 20.04 the lpatop is not booting ... 

Its stuck with the above message .. (the one I have included in the link)

Comment: Are you able to boot to Recovery Mode, and Root Access, from the GRUB menu? Did 20.04 ever boot properly on this machine? Do you have a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB?

Comment: live CD fails to boot in safe graphics as well; I tried it like 5-6 times and one time it started the OS and I was able to install 

but after that regular boot does not go through; safe mode occasionally does

Comment: What I need to see is... in the `terminal`... `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab`. Prefer that you boot to the HDD in safe mode, if required. Copy/paste of the text output is preferable, but if a screenshot or camera shot is all you can do, I'll take it.

Comment: @heynnema with 20.04 my laptop never booted

So I have reverted to 19.10 ... let me try this again in a few days

Comment: Let's check the BIOS. Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the make/model of the laptop, and I'll check for a BIOS update. 20.04 really likes updated BIOS's.

Comment: `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version `
`P05AGQ.033.181123.PS`

The laptop is a samsung laptop --

(https://www.bestbuy.com/site/samsung-notebook-9-pro-15-touch-screen-laptop-intel-core-i7-16gb-memory-amd-radeon-540-256gb-solid-state-drive-titan-silver/6111205.p?skuId=6111205)

Comment: Thanks for the BIOS version info. Unfortunately the Samsung web site just won't give up any BIOS info. You'll have to research this one yourself. Sorry.

Comment: @heynnema I got the bios info, I am not sure if that helps 


wmic bios get smbiosbiosversion
SMBIOSBIOSVersion
P05AGQ.033.181123.PS

Comment: Is P05AGQ.033.181123.PS the value returned when using the `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` command, or the value that your found for the newest BIOS available at some Samsung web site?

Comment: yeah that the value returned when using the `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`

ajax_velu@xubu2:~$ sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
P05AGQ.033.181123.PS

Comment: I still can't find the BIOS update at the Samsung support web site. You'll have to contact Samsung Support directly, by using a link at the web site.